# Realtime chat box inside a 3d game

Tags: c++, objective-c, real-time-data

**Basic information about what going on:**

I have a 3d multiplayer game, there is about only 15-20 users connected. I'm using C++ as coding mixed with objective c, there is a small realtime chatbox sending and recving msg, via a socket based http post request. We are using our another mac as the web/game server/host, where the game/users is connected to.

**My questions:**

Can a socket based http post request be used as a realtime chat inside a 3d multiplayer game?

if yes, is the speed fas or slower?

if no, why not? it works fine with me, the speed is okay fast

Is there any online game with  a socket based http post request used as a realtime chat inside the game itself?

is there any other better metode?

if yes, what and why?

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question - you implemented it yourself, so you know that it's possible; and it's fast enough for your purposes. You don't need to worry about whether there is a better method, unless the method you're currently using is causing problems.

Comment: The only commercial MMO whose chat mechanism I know about for sure was Anarchy Online, which used IRC. (Do I mean "is"? Does *anybody* still play AO?... dunno.)

Comment: Wise words Kevin, true that. mjfgates thanks for pointing that out, now i can research more about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: 
Can a socket based http post request be used as a realtime chat inside a 3d multiplayer game?

**Answer**:
Yes you absolutely can, I used them for a real time client - server model that included real time file transfer (using file chunking) and messaging and it worked well. The speed really depends on how it works for you, I had huge files to chunk and send over to the server but it still worked for me.

**Question**: 
Is there any online game with a socket based http post request used as a realtime chat inside the game itself?

**Answer**:
Obviously NodeJs would be better option, C# and .Net framework Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), but otherwise C++ sockets is a great option.